# Path in vba code for file on a network location

Tags: excel, vba

The below code is to merge data from multiple workbooks  to a single workbook. This macro works on my computer. I want to place this file on network location. I need help for How to make the code workablele on a network location which is not mapped.

```
Sub Mergemom()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtt As Worksheet
Dim sheetfirst As Worksheet
Dim sheetsecond As Worksheet
Dim sheetthird As Worksheet
Dim wbk2 As Workbook
Set wbk2 = ThisWorkbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim Path As String
Path = "E:\Com\"  'CHANGE Folder PATH
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
'OPEN EXCEL FILES
Do While Len(Filename) > 0  'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
wbk.Activate
For Each shtt In wbk.Worksheets
wbk.Activate
Var = shtt.Name
shtt.Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("MOM.xlsm").Activate
Dim lr As Integer
'Var = sht.Name
Sheets(Var).Select
lr =wbk2.Sheets(Var).Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(lr + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
wbk.Close True
Filename = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, put the wrong example: `wbName = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\*workbook name*")
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbName`

Comment: Where to add in code?

Comment: Thanks GMalc. I replace as you said with the following code: wbName = Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MOM.xlsm") Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbName  Now it shows "Compile error: Loop without Do"

Comment: I have tried but not successful to make code workable. Looking for someone help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a [UNC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg465305.aspx) path to the shared folder. Example:

```
Dim path As String
path = "\\server_name\all_users\documents\"
```

If you set up the user privileges on the target folder properly, no one should have issues accessing the shared workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the OS/source share type. I have only done it for 'cifs' shares so I will assume you are on windows, and your share is based on some variation of SMB protocol (even if it is not, this should work)

You can do either \share-name.domain.com\\ or with IP address of share \10.x.x.x\.

To get that share path right click on the mapped drive in windows explorer and you will see it titled (\share-name)(E:).